# Can I use list slicing on my match/case term in Python3

Tags: python, list, switch-statement, match

To elaborate I have a string `x` that will be in the structure of

```
"Test_Case_Box 1"
"Test_Case_Box 2"
"Test_Case_Circle 1"
```

I was using `if` and `elif` statements by checking for example if

```
x[0:19] == "Test_Case_Box"
```

With the match/case syntax if I set the `term` as my string `x`, can I still create if like cases, for example

```
match x:
                case x[0:10] == 'Request_Fun':
                    print(f'-- x[0:10]: {x[0:10]}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use slicing. To use the full benefit of `match`, you can `split` the input:

```py
strs = ["Test_Case_Box 1", "Test_Case_Box 2", "Test_Case_Circle 3"]

for s in strs:
    match s.split():
        case ["Test_Case_Box", num]:
            print(num)
```

Will print:

```
1
2
```

The benefit of using `match` here is that you get both structural matching and assigning variables at one go. Using `if/elif` you will need to parse the structure and then parse inside the conditions to extract the number for example.